# python executable compiled statically with staticx needs sudo permission

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a python application compiled with pyinstaller to an executable. Is there any option available in pyinstaller to include any library statically to the exe? I didn't find a straight forward answer in the pyinstaller documentation. Using a dockerfile environment to build python exe with pyinstaller

```
cmd="pyinstaller --log-level=WARN --specpath ${DIST} --onefile \
        /hostfs/src/main.py -y --clean -n ${EXE_NAME}"
echo $cmd
${cmd}
```

I tried using staticx to include the libz library statically. https://staticx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html
But the application is crashing if used without sudo. Does that mean this library has root privileges and hence the application crashes without root environment?

```
staticx -l /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 <pyinst_built_exe> <new_staticx_exe>
```

The executable should be able to run with or without sudo. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL 2.

```
$ ./staticx-exe --version
 Segmentation fault
$ sudo ./staticx-exe --version
Exe Version - 1.0
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: create a [example]

Comment: yes added the make commands that I am using for pyinstaller and staticx , also added the error that I see on the system.

Comment: It's not at all relevant to your immediate question, but as an aside, `cmd="..."; ${cmd}` is inherently buggy -- see [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) describing why, and what to do instead.

Comment: create an [mre]